# Creating a boolean mask for two 2D arrays representing coordinates of 3D points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, A is an **`(m, 3)`**-shape array and B is an **`(n, 3)`**-shape array with **`m > n`** (this condition is always satisfied. In fact m is at least 3 times n). The two arrays look like this:

```
A = [[x1  y1  z1]                    |  B = [[u1  v1  w1] 
     [x2  y2  z2]                    |       [u2  v2  w2] 
     ...                             |       ...        
     ...                             |       [un  vn  wn]]   
     ...                             |
     ...                             |
     [xm  ym  zm]]                   |
```

**(u, v, w)** and **(x, y, z)** are coordinates of 3D points. All of the points in B exist in A (which contains more points, most are not in B). One thing to note is that *the order of appearance of points in B is **not necessarily** the same in A*, meaning that, for the sake of illustration, **[u1  v1  w1]** can be at position (row) *256*, **[u2  v2  w2]** at *15*, **[u3  v3  w3]** at *569001*, etc.

Another important detail: the coordinates are floats, and if two points correspond, then uk = xj, vk = yj, wk = zj (meaning that the points have the exact position, and are not just close to each other).

I want to create a Boolean mask with the same size as A that will be used later in a code, so that `mask_A = [True, False, False, False, True,..., False]` where `True` means that the point also exists in B, and `False` is put when the point does not appear in B.

I also want to do with it **without any loops**, because the sizes are huge and the procedure of creating the mask is repeated multiple times. I have no problem changing the type of the arrays (turning them into lists, sets, whatever...) as long as it gets the job done and quickly.

I have found multiple answers dealing with masks and 2D arrays, but none of them answer my question.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of A and B? Are they integers of floats? If they are integers, are they relatively small and positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both of them are numpy arrays, you can use the function [numpy.intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

```
_, indices_ar1, _ = numpy.intersect1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False, return_indices=True)
```

I don't know you application but maybe this is enough for you. If not you just have to convert these indices to the binary mask.

Comment: Thank you. I have just found out the solution a few minutes ago and was dabbling with its arguments until I found out the exact syntax you provided. And it works perfectly.